# Material UI Data Grid not working on adding column other than "ID"?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to create a data table from material UI but its giving me below error only on "DT_RowId" field though the id is unique. If I only add "id" then it works fine.
Can anyone please help me on it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sanderson-wn3km?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 7):

You can use `getRowId` prop to return your unique id `DT_RowId`.([Material-ui DataGrid doc](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/))

But it has other cons now. If you want to know detail check this [issue #1119](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1119#issuecomment-787850469).
( In your case, it doesn't affect, so don't worry.)

I modify your code and make it work, like:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "DT_RowId", headerName: "DT_RowId(ID)", width: 150 },
  { field: "color", headerName: "Color", width: 100 },
  { field: "value", headerName: "Value", width: 130 }
];

const rows = [
  {
    DT_RowId: "1",
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
  },
  {
    DT_RowId: "2",
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
  },
  {
    DT_RowId: "3",
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
  },
  {
    DT_RowId: "4",
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
  }
];

export default function DataTable() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        getRowId={(r) => r.DT_RowId}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        checkboxSelection
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the error, [Material-UI Datagrid rows must have a column named `id`](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/getting-started/#define-rows). Otherwise, it won't work. What you can do is map all your `DT_RowId` keys to the `id` key like this,

```
const rowsBeforeMapping = [
  {
    DT_RowId: "1",
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
  },
  {
    DT_RowId: "2",
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
  },
  {
    DT_RowId: "3",
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
  },
  {
    DT_RowId: "4",
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
  }
];

const rows = rowsBeforeMapping.map((row) => {
  const { DT_RowId, ...rest } = row;
  return { id: DT_RowId, ...rest };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I had to do similar thing

https://github.com/prkm93/Data-Table-using-Material-UI/blob/main/src/components/data.js

data.forEach((el, i) => el.DT_RowId = i);

let newData = data.map((el,i) => {
    return {
        id: el.DT_RowId,
        users: el.users,
        sites: el.sites
    }
})

export default newData;

Comment: Instead of running 2 loop you can do that in one loop, as you are not using DT_RowId anymore. You can map index to `id` in the first forEach method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGrid getRowId={row => row.yourUniqueField}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!